# how to solve of removing button label?

Tags: html

I got in trouble that I used these code

```
<input type="image" name="btn_signup_free" id="btn_signup_free" />
```

In firefox it showed well but in internet explorer and google chrome there appears 'submit' at the left top corner which I could not remove.
I placed the background image from css.
thanking you.

Comment: From the code you've shown there isn't a reason why a button with submit should appear. Can you show more code (including relevant CSS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use jQuery for it? Just place an image like this:

```
<form method="post">
<img src="path_to_image/image.jpg" id="executeForm" alt="Some info about img if its not loaded" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#executeForm").click(function()
{
$(this).closest("form").submit();

});
</script>
```

Recently it's quite old fashion to use img as input I guess.